# how to retrieve all events which are stored in EKEventStore without any predicate

Tags: objective-c

how to retrieve all events which are stored in EKEventStore without any predicate

I am getting the ways only based on predicate having startdate and enddate only. can you please help?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The DistantPast and DistantFuture doesn't work, apparently Apple doesn't like it the timespan is too large. However, since you can only get events maximally 2 months in the past anyway, I found out this does work:

```
NSDate *startDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:-604800*10];   //This is 10 weeks in seconds   
NSPredicate *pred = [self.eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:startDate endDate:[NSDate distantFuture] calendars:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit (1/30/17): This answer is outdated; see Bob's answer above.**

--

Sorry, this answer might be a bit late, but for those who get here searching for this:

You still need to use a predicate, but you can just put the start date as [NSDate distantPast] and the end date as [NSDate distantFuture]

For example, this would fetch all the calendar events for the calendars included in "calendarArray" provided that you have an EKEventStore called "eventStore":

```
NSPredicate *fetchCalendarEvents = [self.eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:[NSDate distantPast] endDate:[NSDate distantFuture] calendars:calendarArray];

NSArray *allEvents = [self.eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:fetchCalendarEvents];
```

Comment: By the way, if you wanted to fetch events from all calendars on the device, you can just use the following to define calendarArray: NSArray *calendarArray = eventStore.calendars;

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me. Not sure EKEventStore does what you'd expect with [NSDate distantPast] and [NSDate distantFuture]...